# How to find the max array from both sides

Tags: python

Given an integer array `A`, I need to pick `B` elements from either left or right end of the array `A` to get maximum sum. If `B = 4`, then you can pick the first four elements or the last four elements or one from front and three from back etc.

Example input:

```py
A = [5, -2, 3, 1, 2]
B = 3
```

The correct answer is `8` (by picking `5` from the left, and `1` and `2` from the right).

My code:

```py
def solve(A, B):
    n = len(A)
    # track left most index and right most index i,j
    i = 0
    j = n-1
    Sum = 0
    B2 = B  # B for looping and B2 for reference it
    # Add element from front
    for k in range(B):
        Sum += A[k]
        
    ans = Sum
    # Add element from last
    for _ in range(B2):
       # Remove element from front
       Sum -= A[i]
       # Add element from last
       Sum += A[j]
       ans = max(ans, Sum)

    return ans
```

But the answer I get is `6`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

```py
def max_bookend_sum(x, n):
    bookends = x[-n:] + x[:n]
    return max(sum(bookends[i : i + n]) for i in range(n + 1))
```

### Explanation

Let `n = 3` and take `x`,

```py
>>> x = [4, 9, -7, 4, 0, 4, -9, -8, -6, 9]
```

Grab the "right" `n` elements, concatenate with the "left" `n`:

```py
>>> bookends = x[-n:] + x[:n]
>>> bookends  # last three elements from x, then first three
[-8, -6, 9, 4, 9, -7]
```

Take "sliding window" groups of `n` elements:

```py
>>> [bookends[i : i + n] for i in range(n + 1)]
[[-8, -6, 9], [-6, 9, 4], [9, 4, 9], [4, 9, -7]]
```

Now, instead of producing the sublists sum them instead, and take the max:

```py
>>>  max(sum(bookends[i : i + n]) for i in range(n + 1))
22
```

For your large array `A` from the comments:

```py
>>> max(sum(bookends[i : i + n]) for i in range(n + 1))
6253
```

Comment: in this approach I need first element and last two element also. I could not find that in this solution like 4,9,-6, first two element and last element 9,4,9

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: lets take x = 3, in this, first a[0], a[-1], a[-2] makes 3 elements

Comment: This solution does that... If `x = "abcdefg"` and `n = 3` then the 3-element groups are `'efg', 'fga', 'gab', 'abc'`, i.e. they "wrap" around from the end of the array to the front.

Comment: i got it, correct output thanks, but where its doing that operation, i could not find, which step

Comment: also why you adding x[-n:] + x[:n], here n = 3, but you got 6 elements by doing that

Comment: That's taking the `n` rightmost elements, and the `n` leftmost elements. You do this so that you can make the "sliding windows". See my comment which uses letters instead of numbers. Imagine taking your array and curling it into a ring where the last element is adjacent to the first element.

Answer (score 1):

Solution based on sum of the left and right slices:

```
Data = [-533, -666, -500, 169, 724, 478, 358, -38, -536, 705, -855, 281, -173, 961, -509, -5, 942, -173, 436, -609,
        -396, 902, -847, -708, -618, 421, -284, 718, 895, 447, 726, -229, 538, 869, 912, 667, -701, 35, 894, -297, 811,
        322, -667, 673, -336, 141, 711, -747, -132, 547, 644, -338, -243, -963, -141, -277, 741, 529, -222, -684,
        35]  # to avoid var shadowing


def solve(A, B):
    m, ln = None, len(A)
    for i in range(B):
        r = -(B-i-1)  # r is right index to slice
        tmp = sum(A[0:i + 1]) + sum(A[r:]) if r < 0 else 0
        m = tmp if m is None else max(m, tmp)
    return m


print(solve(Data, 48))  # 6253
```

Comment: Can you explain, this is too much for me

Comment: also where i did my mistake

Comment: I got wrong answer for below

Comment: A : [ -533, -666, -500, 169, 724, 478, 358, -38, -536, 705, -855, 281, -173, 961, -509, -5, 942, -173, 436, -609, -396, 902, -847, -708, -618, 421, -284, 718, 895, 447, 726, -229, 538, 869, 912, 667, -701, 35, 894, -297, 811, 322, -667, 673, -336, 141, 711, -747, -132, 547, 644, -338, -243, -963, -141, -277, 741, 529, -222, -684, 35 ]
B : 48

Comment: expected is 6253
, i got 114

Comment: See updated solution

Answer (score 1):

A recursive approach with comments.

```
def solve(A, B, start_i=0, end_i=None):

    # set end_i to the index of last element
    if end_i is None:
        end_i = len(A) - 1

    # base case 1: we have no more moves
    if B == 0:
        return 0

    # base case 2: array only has two elemens
    if end_i - start_i == 1:
        return max(A)

    # next, we need to choose whether to use one of our moves on 
    # the left side of the array or the right side. We compute both, 
    # then check which one is better. 
    
    # pick the left side to sum
    sum_left = A[start_i] + solve(A, B - 1, start_i + 1, end_i)

    # pick the right side to sum
    sum_right = A[end_i] + solve(A, B - 1, start_i, end_i - 1)

    # return the max of both options
    return max(sum_left, sum_right)

arr = [5, -2, 3, 1, 2]
print(solve(arr, 3)) # prints 8
```

Comment: Recursion is a bad idea for this problem. It's an extreme memory hog, and takes *forever* to run for moderately sized inputs, like OP's example from the comments of [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69240205/6298712) In fact, it still has not resolved since I started writing this comment.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is if we have this list:

```
[5, 1, 1, 8, 2, 10, -2]
```

Then the possible numbers for `B=3` would be:

```
lhs = [5,  1,  1]  # namely L[+0], L[+1], L[+2]
rhs = [2, 10, -2]  # namely R[-3], R[-2], R[-1]
```

The possible combinations would be:

```
[5,  1,  1]  # L[+0], L[+1], L[+2]
[5,  1, -2]  # L[+0], L[+1], R[-1]
[5, 10, -2]  # L[+0], R[-2], R[-1]
[2, 10, -2]  # R[-3], R[-2], R[-1]
```

As you can see, we can easily perform forward and backward iterations which will start from all L (L[+0], L[+1], L[+2]), and then iteratively replacing the last element with an R (R[-1], then R[-2], then R[-3]) up until all are R (R[-3], then R[-2], then R[-1]).

```
def solve(A, B):
    n = len(A)
    max_sum = None
    for lhs, rhs in zip(range(B, -1, -1), range(0, -(B+1), -1)):
        combined = A[0:lhs] + (A[rhs:] if rhs < 0 else [])
        combined_sum = sum(combined)
        max_sum = combined_sum if max_sum is None else max(max_sum, combined_sum)
    return max_sum

for A in [
    [5, 1, 1, 8, 2, 10, -2],
    [5, 6, 1, 8, 2, 10, -2],
    [5, 6, 3, 8, 2, 10, -2],
]:
    print(A)
    print("\t1 =", solve(A, 1))
    print("\t2 =", solve(A, 2))
    print("\t3 =", solve(A, 3))
    print("\t4 =", solve(A, 4))
```

**Output**

```
[5, 1, 1, 8, 2, 10, -2]
    1 = 5
    2 = 8
    3 = 13
    4 = 18
[5, 6, 1, 8, 2, 10, -2]
    1 = 5
    2 = 11
    3 = 13
    4 = 20
[5, 6, 3, 8, 2, 10, -2]
    1 = 5
    2 = 11
    3 = 14
    4 = 22
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int solve(int[] A, int B) {
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int n = A.length -1;
    for (int k = 0; k < B; k++){
        sum += A[k];
    }
    int ans = sum;
    int B2 = B -1;
    for (int j = n; j > n -B; j--){
        sum -= A[B2];
        sum += A[j];
        ans = Math.max(ans, sum);
        B2--;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).